# how to map value from another dataframe to header of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4],
                    'B':[5,6,7,8],
                    'D':[9,10,11,12]})
```

and

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'type':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
                    'color':['yellow', 'green', 'red', 'pink', 'black'],
                    'size':['S', 'M', 'L', 'S', 'M']})
```

I want to map Information from df2 to Header of df1, the result should look like below:

[image]

how can I do this? Many thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `rename` with aggregate values by [`DataFrame.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A1':[1,2,3,4],
                    'B':[5,6,7,8],
                    'D':[9,10,11,12]})


s = df2.set_index('type', drop=False).agg(','.join, axis=1)
df1 = df1.rename(columns=s)
print (df1)
   A1  B,green,M  D,pink,S
0   1          5         9
1   2          6        10
2   3          7        11
3   4          8        12
```

For `()` need more processing:

```
s = df2.set_index('type').agg(','.join, axis=1).add(')').radd('(')
s = s.index +' ' + s
df1 = df1.rename(columns=s)
print (df1)
   A (yellow,S)  B (green,M)  D (pink,S)
0             1            5           9
1             2            6          10
2             3            7          11
3             4            8          12
```